# Problemas con un Componente de Servicios de Componentes

Tags: c#, servicio, outlook

Estoy desarrollando un Servicio en C# que utiliza el Proceso de Outlook. Incicialmente me fallaba mientras el Outlook estaba ya en marcha. Buscando soluciones encontré una que me hacía ir a Servicios de Componentes y desde allí buscar el Componente DCOM 'Outlook Message Attachment', entrar en propiedades e ir a la pestaña 'Identidad' y cambiar el valor de Cuenta de Usuario para Ejecutar poner 'El Usuario Interactivo'.

Con ese cambio me empezó a funcionar el servicio y lo pude terminar.

El problema me viene cuando quiero instalar ese servicio en una serie de máquinas y me encuentro que en Servicios de Componentes no tienen en DCOM el componente indicado, el 'Outlook Message Attachment'.

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo añadir el componente en las máquinas que no lo tienen que es esencial para que me funcione el servicio en las máquinas que lo tengo que instalar.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si tu programa se basa en un componente de un tercero (Outlook en este caso), seguramente tendrás que instalar dicho programa en los equipos sobre los cuales desees ejecutar tu programa. No conozco totalmente la estructura DCOM y no sabría decirte si dicho componente puedes aislarlo del paquete Outlook, pienso que no, además es probable que necesites la misma versión que tienes en tu equipo de desarrollo. Saludos

Comment: La cuestión es saber el programa que instala dicho componente, o si hay forma de añadir manualmente el componente.